# Java Spring Security conifguration - error code 302 when adding new user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

An implementation for login, register and logout has been done and it was tested in postman, what behaved as it should be.

Although, when I tried to build the forms to process the authentication, I had encountered with several problems.

In short, I have implemented a login.html and a register.html. Both service has separate controllers. See below for further details

`register.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="post" action="/register">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required><br><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
    <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`login.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<!-- Display error message if there is a login error -->
<div th:if="${error}">
    <p style="color: red;">Incorrect username or password.</p>
</div>
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <label for="email">email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required><br><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <a href="/register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `LoginController` and `RegisterController`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegisterController {

    private final AuthenticationService authService;

    @GetMapping
    public String showRegisterForm() {
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        System.out.println("I'm here");
        AuthenticationResponse authResponse = authService.register(new RegistrationRequest(username,  password));
        // Set token as cookie
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("jwtToken", authResponse.getAccessToken());
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        return "dashboard";
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginController {

    private final AuthenticationService authService;

    @GetMapping
    public String showLoginForm() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        try{
            AuthenticationResponse authResponse = authService.authenticate(new AuthenticationRequest(username, password));
            // Set token as cookie
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("jwtToken", authResponse.getAccessToken());
            cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            return "redirect:/dashboard";
        }catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            model.addAttribute("error", true);
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I will provide the `securityFilterChain' config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAthFilter jwtAthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/dashboard").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/account").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/register").permitAll())
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I think somehow it is related to a misconfiguration in the SecurityConfig class. Since when I try to send a post by registering I every time got back to the register page.

The first problem, which may be the root cause is the following:

1. The webapp is launched.
2. The register.html form is correclty displayed
3. Inserted values in the password and username fields
4. When pressing the submit button, an error code `302` appears and the page is redirected to the
   `http://localhost:5000/register?error` url

Notes:

1. I also tried to access the `http://localhost:5000/dashboard` URL and it is not accessible however it is defined as it should be
2. I experienced in debug mode that, the `POST` reguest in the `RegisterController` is not invoked since the log was not displayed and didn't stop at the breakpoint
3. Also no user was created in the database (maybe the flow doesn't reach that point becasue of the error code `302`.

Unfortunately, most of the answers are declaring the deprecated `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class so I thought it would be a good idea discussing about this topic for other newbies.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, but i will leave the question open in case somebody has the same error:

Do not use in the securityFilterChain the following property to register new user:

`.formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/register.html").permitAll())`

instead of do it as it should be with `requestMatchers()`:

`.requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()`

Seems to be straightforward, but this is also part of the process.

Good luck!